# redirect to http depending on condition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, server, devops

I use nginx

Assume that url **hello.test.example.com**, hello example of dynamically subdomain, how can i redirect to **hello.test2.example.com** when hello file existing in specific directory path

```
server_name ~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+)\.test\.example\.com$;
    set $m_file /home/files/$subdomain;
    if (-f $m_file) {
           rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$subdomain.test2.example.com/;
    }
```

this condition working when the url **(hello.test.example.com)** but when the url **(hello.test.example.com\en)** working but not every time ! why ?